# Using segues to display a UIView from UITableViewController

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uitableview, segue

I am trying to connect a UITableViewController to a UIView using storyboards. I have a TabBarController that connects to a Navigation Controller that displays a UITableViewController, displaying a small array. I want to click on a row and that trigger a simple UIView with a label, still displayed in the UINavigationController so I can navigate back to the UITableViewController

I can get the UITableViewController to display OK, with the array, but I can't get the row to trigger when I select it.

This is my UITableViewController (AtoZController.m) file:

```
#import "AtoZController.h"
#import "StoreDetailsView.h"

@interface AtoZController ()

@end

@implementation AtoZController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"A to Z", @"An A to Z List of Stores");

    AtoZArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [AtoZArray addObject:@"Apple"];
    [AtoZArray addObject:@"Boots"];
    [AtoZArray addObject:@"Topman"];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [AtoZArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [AtoZArray objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;
}
```

I have a segue connected, named storeDetailsSegue, from the UITableViewController to a UIView. I am attempting to use the prepareForSeque method to trigger the next view but have had no luck with the following code.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    StoreDetailsView *detail = [self detailForIndexPath:path];
    [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:detail];
}
```

As it keeps saying there is an error as there is 'No visible @interface for "AtoZController declares the selector 'detailForIndexPath'". I may be doing something completely wrong as I have never used storyboards before. What I want is for a simple UIView to display a label that dynamically changes to display the row number that has been selected.

I don't know if the UITableViewController should infact be a UITableView but as I have never used segues or storyboards I have no idea what could be causing the problem.

Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

So I managed to get the UIViewController to display but still can't get the label to update before I display the view.

Comment: OK. So I've figured out all I need to do was add the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method with this:

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"storeDetailsSegue" sender:self]; 
}

*HEADDESK* moment